# I want to add adsense for my blog

Tags: google-adsense

I made [a blog](http://www.mycsnippets.blogspot.com) few months back,I wanted to add adsense for it but yesterday I found out that the e-mail address I use is blacklisted by google adsense,I have applied for google adsense some years back but they replied back that the site did not had much content.Why would they blacklist my email address?Can I have a new adsense account?

Comment: Yes I think you can. Did you try creating a new gmail account and apply for a new adsense account?!

Comment: Yes I have made a new account and applied for adsense but they replied back saying that the page content was not of standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They usually don't allow adsense for what they deem to be "personal content". I've tried it before on a personal blog. Also (as you found out) they only allow ads once the site has a fair bit of content on it.

I can't find a link to it, but I suspect that's the reason.

**Update**

Ok, I've read around a bit and it *might* be that it refers to the content between the [targeting tags](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=23168) that you're supposed to put in your HTML. Maybe there's not enough content between the tags?

Comment: You think my blog has personal content?

Comment: I don't know since I haven't seen your blog, but it's something that I've come up against before. It's more than likely the second part of my answer, about content.

Comment: How many posts do you think should be enough before applying for adsense?(any idea)?